# Change fill colors in contingency plot in R

Tags: r, plot, survey, contingency

I try to to change the colors of a contingency plot in R that is created with the `survey` package. Unfortunately only the colors of the rows from the contingency table are changed. Is there a way to give each of the four fields below an individual color?

Here is what I tried:

```
library("survey")
data(api)
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
plot(svytable(~sch.wide+comp.imp,design=dstrat),
     color=c("red","blue","green","black"))
```

[image: Contingency Plot with survey package]

Comment: This plot is actually from `graphics:::plot.table` and isn't a `survey` specific plot.

Comment: @zacdav Just out of curiosity: how did you find out which method gets deployed? It seems that the table in question is of type `svytable`. Been wondering how to trace down which `plot.___` is actually working...

Comment: @coffeinjunky so i looked at the classes of the object being provided to `plot()` and then checked if they returned anything from `methods("plot")`. Then just manually tried the methods to see what produced the same plot. You can probably use a profiling tool to see it as well.